# Benefits of composition over inheritance in React

Tags: reactjs, inheritance, composition

I'm having a hard time substituting inheritance for composition in React. I'll try to explain the problem posed and my current solution, based on inheritance which is  discouraged in the React style guide.

First, I define common state and methods in a super component:

```
export default class SuperComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = commonState;
    }

    foo() {
        this.setState({a: 3});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.getContent()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Then I make subcomponents with potentially more state and methods. These should also have access to the state of the supercomponent though:

```
export default class SubComponent1 extends SuperComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = Object.assign(this.state, subComponent1State);
    }

    bar() {
        this.setState({b: 7});
    }

    getContent() {
        return (
            <div>
                I'm subcomponent 1
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default class SubComponent2 extends SuperComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = Object.assign(this.state, subComponent2State);
    }

    bar() {
        this.setState({c: 1});
    }

    getContent() {
        return (
            <div>
                I'm subcomponent 2
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

When I try to convert this into an composition based approach I get this:

```
export default class SuperComponent extends Component {
    foo() {
        this.props.setStateMethod({a: 3});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {this.props.text}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default class SubComponent1 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = Object.assign(commonState, subComponent1State);
    }

    bar() {
        this.setState({b: 7});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SuperComponent
                text={"I'm subcomponent 1"}
                setStateMethod={this.setState}
                subComponentState={this.state}
            />
        )
    }
}

export default class SubComponent2 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = Object.assign(commonState, subComponent2State);
    }

    bar() {
        this.setState({c: 1});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SuperComponent
                text={"I'm subcomponent 2"}
                setStateMethod={this.setState}
                subComponentState={this.state}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Is this a good way to go about converting the inheritance based solution to a composition based one? Isn't the inheritance based one better since common and differentiated state are better separated? In the composition based solution, one has to define common state in every sub component on initialisation.

Comment: Common state can be handled by container components hat inject the state as props.  This is real separation of state because it is now owned by a dedicated component and others do not need to know how to manage that state. In your example the state of the sub components should be lifted up to the parent if they share that state.

Answer (score 5):

First off, you should read [React's Team response on the matter](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).

The code is pretty vague, so I can't tell if your case is really special, but I doubt it, so let me tackle the general consensus:

Inheritance and Composition are, in a vacuum, equally useful. In some languages or projects, you'll prefer a common class to inherit from, than a dozen functions to import and call, but in React, mainly because it's component-centric approach, the oposite is true.

Composition keeps React about just two things: `props` and `state`. You trust what you receive, act in a predictable way and reflect both `props` and `state` in what you render. If you need to change slightly what you render, you can send down different `props`, maybe even make a component that wraps the first one for that specific use. That component can even have some logic on it's own, and pass it down through [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) so you can control the result with even more precision. If you need to wrap different components with this logic you can make a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) and wrap any component easily. At that point you can make dozens of components that return different things to the same `props` and can switch between a library of components to display the data and to handle it.

Although things like Render props or HOCs look like different things, they are just techniques that use the already existing component logic and apply it in ways that let you reuse code and still make sense within React. Is it a good solution? Well, it works, but you end up in wrapping hell and juggling twenty concepts that are pretty much the same. That's why there is now a [proposal](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) for a paradigm changing new feature that is midway between inheritance and composition. But composition still makes less sense in the React way of doing things.

At the end of the day is just a different way of looking at the same problem. Composition just works better with React, and gives you more control in `render` to mix and match what you need.

Again, if you have a practical example I could give you a better explanation applying different React techniques, but with your current one, clearly there isn't a good or bad way to do it, since it does nothing. This takes some time tinkering more than an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your solution is the best composition-based solution in this case. Since you want the subcomponents to have their own state (and I assume they will have their own logic), I would use a [hoc](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) like this:

```js
// hoc.js
const withSuper = (SubComponent) => {
  class WithSuper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);
    }

    foo() { // could also receive a value
      this.props.setState({ a: 3 });
    }

    render() {
      // Passes to the SubComponent:
        // the state.a as a prop
        // function foo to modify state.a
        // the rest of the props that may be passed from above
      return (
        <SubComponent
          a={this.state.a}
          foo={this.foo}
          {...this.props}
        />
      )
    }
  }

  return WithSuper;
};


// SubComponent1.js
class SubComponent1 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { b: 0 }; // or anything else
    }

    bar() {
      this.setState({b: 7});
    }

    render() {
      // to access the 'a' value use: this.props.a
      // to modify the 'a' value call: this.props.foo()
      return (
        <div>
          I'm subcomponent 1
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default withSuper(SubComponent1);
```

The `SubComponent2` would also be wrapped: `withSuper(SubComponent2)`, so it could also access `a` and `foo()` props.

I think this solution is better, because the hoc "Super" encapsulates the behavior of `a`, and the sub-components only have to worry about modifying their specific state.